# no module named fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, fuzzywuzzy

I installed fuzzywuzzy with pip for python3. When I do pip list I see

```
fuzzywuzzy (0.8.1)
```

However when I try to import is I get an error.

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fuzzywuzzy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'fuzzywuzzy'
>>>
```

Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you ran `pip3` and not just `pip`? The latter only installs Python 2 packages.

Comment: @Harald I have followed what you suggested, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: that is not the answer above. pip3 seems to be unrelated to the issue. FuzzyWuzzy is installed but for some reason Collecting fuzzywuzzy
  Using cached fuzzywuzzy-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Installing collected packages: fuzzywuzzy
Successfully installed fuzzywuzzy-0.18.0

Answer (score 2):

Go to anaconda prompt and try

```
pip3 install fuzzywuzzy
```

You can follow this documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to upgrade your pip

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip --upgrade --user
```

Then install fuzzywuzzy

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org fuzzywuzzy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Spyder. Check your Python version by:

```
import sys 
print(sys.executable)
```

And use what the previous command returns. For instance, if it returns "/usr/bin/python3", then run the following command:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

Answer (score -3):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy

From the document, if you want to use some functions of the library, type

`from fuzzywuzzy import {the name of the function}`

Comment: That doesn't explain why the OP's module is not found